# Pass 1 float from array to vertex shader for every vertex

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have to draw a sphere (I already managed to do this) using it's parametric formula.

I also have to generate an array with as many values as there are vertices (I also managed to do this). The values need to range from 0.95 to 1.05.

I have to pass this array to the vertex shader as a uniform and have to multiply every vertex of the sphere with the corresponding value from the array (this should create an Earth-looking sphere).

The problem is that I can't seem to pass the array as a uniform and even if I could, I don't understand how I could choose the corresponding value from the array that I have to multiply it with.

```
in vec3 pos;
in vec3 col;
uniform float arr[];

out vec3 out_col;

uniform mat4 mtr;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mtr * vec4(pos, 1) * vec4(arr[someIndex], 1);
    out_col = col;
}
```

arr[] is the array containing the values for every vertex. pos is the current vertex and col is the current color. What should someIndex be and how can I pass an array as uniform?

Comment: *"the array containing the values for every vertex"* - If there is one array element for each vertex, so why do you not use another attribute?

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I tried it but when I multiplied the vertex with the value the sphere disappeared.

Comment: I din't know, I can guess only, because you didn't provide enough information. What have you tried? What are your data structures? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).